# z-index not working. How to get my text show ontop of the image

Tags: css, jquery-ui-slider, jquery-slider

I am using royalslider. 
I have this

```
<a class="rsImg" data-rsDelay="1000" href="image.jpg">
  <span>This is caption <b>HTML1</b> text</span>
</a>
```

this works fine and put the text under the image. However, I want to show the text on top of the image. But when I move the text up, it goes under the picture not on top.
I tried this

```
<a class="rsImg" data-rsDelay="1000" href="image.jpg" style="z-index:-10000 !important;">
  <span style="z-index:10000 !important;margin-top:-100px;">
    This is caption <b>HTML1</b> text
  </span>
</a>
```

but that didnt work. any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

> Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

Answer (score 3):

Like mentioned add this to your css:

```
position: relative;
```

then it should work, in this case relative positioning is what I would use.

Answer (score 1):

The z-index does not work if you do not use position. It works best if you have called position absolute.